# How to get a div on-click on drop down item using ng-if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario, in that I have custom dropdown, for example the drop consists list of qualifications, in that first item would be the qualification, so when I select on qualification, I get a question like what is your qualification?

So here is my requirement. When I click on that question again I need to open a div based on `ng-if` condition and how to give the `ng-click` for the binded question when I select area.

HTML:

```
<ul class="select">
    <li ng-click="selfprofileCtrlAs.edit()">Area</li>
    <li ng-repeat="aa in areas" ng-click="IdFunc(Id,Name)">{{aa.Name}}</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.areas=[
  {
    Id:1,
    Name:ss
  },
  {
    Id:2,
    Name:pp
  },
  {
    Id:3,
    Name:kk
  },
  {
    Id:4,
    Name:dd
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you using the `controllerAs` synthax?

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
<li ng-repeat="aa in areas" ng-click="IdFunc(Id,Name)">{{aa.Name}}</li>
```

Instead, you can pass the current object throw the function with the following syhntax:

```
<li ng-repeat="aa in areas" ng-click="IdFunc(aa)">{{aa.Name}}</li>
```

So, in `IdFunc()`:

```
$scope.IdFunc = function(area) {
    console.log(area); /* Access the clicked area */   
}
```